# The configuration of postgresql.conf for PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a server with 32GB RAM, Windows platform. Out of that 8GB is assigned to JVM. 500 is the max number of postgres connections. Database size is around 24GB. Postgres Version is 9.2.3
What can be the best configuration in postgresql.conf.
I am a newbie in postgres database. Appreciate your help.

This is the current configuration

```
max_connections = 500
shared_buffers = 1GB
temp_buffers = 512MB
work_mem = 24MB             
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB        
wal_buffers = 8MB
effective_cache_size = 8GB
```

Comment: `shared_buffers` looks quite low. You should be able to raise that to 8GB. You should set `wal_buffers` to `-1` to let Postgres choose the size. Also: Postgres 9.2 will be end-of-live in about 6 months. You should start planning your upgrade to 9.6 now.

Comment: `max_connections = 500` looks quite high. Do you really need these? (maybe a connection pooler would be a better way) effective_cache_size looks rather low (but I don't know Windows)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your suggestion. 9.6 upgrade plan is ON. Do shared_buffer have any connections with the number of connection.

Comment: @wildplasser I have monitored the connections in a day and peak time. Its around 370-400 on the peak. So safer side I have given 500.